# Editor with inline SVN diff support (like in Netbeans)?

Tags: eclipse, macos, svn, editor, diff

I'm trying to abandon Netbeans as my primary code editor. One thing I like about Netbeans is how it displays file changes - see **[screenshot](http://img190.imagevenue.com/img.php?image=929827212_netbeans_inline_svn_diff_122_159lo.jpg)**. The colored bars give the same information as `svn diff`. Hovering on these bars gives the option to see the diff or revert this particular change (vs. the whole file).

**What other OS X editors/IDEs have a similar feature?**

Bonus question: does this feature have a particular name?

**UPDATE** for someone finding this question later:

With the help of phatfingers's answer, I did some further research myself to find out that **Netbeans** and **Eclipse+Subclipse** seem to be the only options offering what I was looking for.

Eclipse seems to call this *Quick Diff*. There's a preference to diff the current version against *Pristine SVN Copy*.

For the record, I'm moving to some other editor anyway. Subclipse is (still) horrible to configure on OS X, and Eclipse seems quite bloated for my purposes. Also, Eclipse's Quick Diff is no match for what is in Netbeans. Netbeans colors the diff blocks in the gutter quite more clearly, and you can revert each individual change with a click.

Although many editors provide "non-quick" svn diffs, I'll probably handle my svn diffing on the command line, with eg. `svn diff | grcat conf.diff`.

Or maybe I'll write a plugin for some other editor. :)

**UPDATE 2: I wrote a [quickdiff plugin to Komodo Edit / Komodo IDE](https://github.com/tuomassalo/komodo-quickdiff)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** Sublime Text has [Vcs Gutter](https://github.com/bradsokol/VcsGutter) and [Git Gutter](https://github.com/jisaacks/GitGutter), of which Vcs Gutter is a fork.

Answer (score 3):

The Eclipse IDE with the Subclipse plugin does a nice job of that, showing you which files changed, allowing you to compare prior versions to see changes over time, detecting which changes involve conflicts, and providing visual tools that allow you to hand-pick individual changes.

I think the class of application is called a "Merge Client" or more specifically a "Graphical Subversion Client" (as you mentioned SVN).

Comment: There's a fairly comprehensive set of comparisons here:  https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Comparison_of_Subversion_clients

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220111/subclipse-marking-code-changes-like-in-netbeans for more details