# STS how to mark code changes like in Netbeans?

Tags: svn, spring-tool-suite

I found a similar solution to what I need in a topic 
[similar topic for eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220111/subclipse-marking-code-changes-like-in-netbeans)
and since STS is based on Eclipse I managed to set the same properties.

It seemed to work initially, like mark new and changed lines,
but after the save all these markings disappear!

Has someone a clue, what to do to make it last?

(STS version is 3.9.1 on Linux Mint Sonya
SVNKit and Subclipse)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my project was not properly checked-out
so the markings didn't function.

With proper checkout the code changes stay persistent.